# Excel Index + if + indirect

Tags: arrays, excel, lookup, excel-indirect

I am helping a friend with a work task he's been given and can't figure out the last part. We are given a matrix with a list of workers / users in the following layout:

```
Location  | First Name | Last Name | Property 1 | Property 2 | Property 3 | .. | Property N
Frankfurt | Adam       | Schmidt   | X          |            | X          | .. | X,
```

i.e. the properties are in boolean form (X to indicate 'Yes', or empty to indicate 'No').

The task is to search all users based on Location + 1 property that we are able to select from the N properties, i.e. we have a drop-down menu somewhere with all properties 1,2,..,N where we can select exactly 1 of the properties.

The output should be the format: Location | First Name | Last Name.

So, my idea was to replace the standard IF(("array for criteria 1"= "criteria 1") * ("array for criteria 2" = "yes"), ...) with the ADDRESS of the property we select, which we then transformed from text value into cell reference using the INDIRECT function.

To give an example, if we select property 1 (located in column D) in the drop-down menu, the ADDRESS function will return $D$1 as the starting field, and $D$100 as the ending field. These fields are then used inside an INDIRECT function inside the main (long) search function.

I've seen from other posts on the [internet](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm) that it is possible to use SUM(INDIRECT(cell with starting cell defined&":"&cell with ending cell defined)), so I tried something similar in my function, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is a picture of the formula & layout of the excel file.
[image: picture]

Comment: Wouldn't an [Advanced Filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Advanced-filter-details-BBD0CB0A-8F90-43DF-BF77-6AD3774DC420) be appropriate for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should organize your sheet into 3 sections:

1. Data set
2. Criteria
3. Result Set

[image: Advanced Filter]

Follow the steps to create the button action for Search.

1. Navigate to 'Developer' tab.
2. Click on Insert > Button.
3. Draw a button. The 'Assign Macro' dialog box will be displayed.
4. Click on Record.
5. Enter the macro name as 'SearchRecords' and click on OK.
6. Click on any empty cell. Navigate to 'Data' tab.
7. In the 'Sort & Filter' section click on 'Advanced'.
8. Select 'Copy to another location' radio button and enter the range based on data set and criteria locations.

[image: Select Advanced Filter options]

9. Click on OK.
10. Navigate to 'Developer' tab and click on 'Stop Recording'.
11. Rename the button to 'Search'.

Now you can update the search criteria and click on the search button to update the results in the adjacent location.

Comment: This approach is working fine for the minimal version that I have, I'm not waiting for the confirmation of my friend that is working for him in the original file.

Out of curiosity, is there any way to make my idea work?

Comment: Unfortuntately, in the approach you mentioned we cannot ascertain how many records will be returned in search result. So the formula has to be applied to the entire column or atleast the total number of records in data set. Also this is a very messy way of doing things via formula. You'd rather just create a macro for it instead.

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way would be to organize your input data as follows:
[image: Pivot friendly data]

This data set is Pivot friendly. You can then create a Pivot Table of the data set. Move the Location and Property fields to the Report Filter section, the Full Name to the Row Labels section and the Location to the Values section.

Please note Full Name is just a concatenated value of 'First Name' & 'Last Name'.

Comment: I asked my friend about this solution, he said this approach would destroy many relations that are existent in the original file (that contains more tabs & data).